# How to migrate restlet filter to spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, restlet

I'm starting to migrate a [restlet](http://restlet.com/) based application to [spring mvc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html).

Currently we use restlet [Filters](http://restlet.com/learn/javadocs/2.1/jse/api/org/restlet/routing/Filter.html) for security and logging. What's the best approach to migrate this filters to spring mvc? I was thinking about aspects added to the action methods via annotation. Is this the spring way to implement filters?

Comment: you can configure a custom FIlterChainProxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for filters, you can use [Spring MVC Interceptors](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor).
For security, you normaly use Spring Security which can be based on annotations, if you want, or endpoint-configuration (e.g. /admin/* should be secured)